# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference only in IE9 only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I only receive this error in Internet Explorer 9.  IE8 and IE10 run the script fine. when click on the Submit button then i am getting this error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference CNSIControlServlet, line 15364 character 3

```
function checkForPhysicianInfo(){

    var visibleRenderingPhyInfoValue  = (document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['fhdn&BillingRendering']).value;
    var visibleOperatePhyInfoValue  = (document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['fhdn&isOperatePhyInfoVisible']).value;
    var visibleOtherOperatingPhyInfoValue  = (document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['fhdn&isOtherOperatingPhyInfoVisible']).value;
    var visibleReferringPhyInfoValue  = (document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['fhdn&isReferringPhyInfoVisible']).value;
    var formName1='frmSubmitInstClaim';
    var  formElement = document.forms[formName1];
    var l_sRenderingProviderID = document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['nfld_a&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-SRVCNG_PRVDR_LCTN_IDENTIFIER'];
    var selectRenderingProviderIDType = formElement.elements['ncmb&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-SRVCNG_PRVDR_IDNTFR_TYPE_CID'];
    RenderingProviderIDType = selectRenderingProviderIDType.options[selectRenderingProviderIDType.selectedIndex].value ;

    var l_sOperateProviderID =document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['nfld_a&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-OP_PRVDR_IDNTFR'];
    var selectOperateProviderIDType = formElement.elements['ncmb&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-OP_PRVDR_IDNTFR_TYPE_CID'];
    OperateProviderIDType = selectOperateProviderIDType.options[selectOperateProviderIDType.selectedIndex].value ;

    var l_sOtherOperatingProviderID =document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['nfld_a&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-OT_PRVDR_IDNTFR'];
    var selectOtherOperatingProviderIDType = formElement.elements['ncmb&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-OT_PRVDR_IDNTFR_TYPE_CID'];
    OtherOperatingProviderIDType = selectOtherOperatingProviderIDType.options[selectOtherOperatingProviderIDType.selectedIndex].value ;


    var l_sReferringProviderID =document.frmSubmitInstClaim.elements['nfld_a&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-RF_LCTN_IDENTIFIER'];
    var selectReferringProviderIDType = formElement.elements['ncmb&db|IG_CLAIM_HEADER-RF_IDNTFR_TYPE_CID'];
    ReferringProviderIDType = selectReferringProviderIDType.options[selectReferringProviderIDType.selectedIndex].value ;

    if("Yes" == visibleRenderingPhyInfoValue)
    {
        if(Trim(l_sRenderingProviderID.value) == "" )
        {
            alert("Please Enter Rendering Physican Provider ID ");
            l_sRenderingProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(Trim(RenderingProviderIDType) == "-2" )
        {
            alert("Please Enter Rendering Physican Provider ID Type");
            selectRenderingProviderIDType.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 
        if((Trim(RenderingProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sRenderingProviderID.value)!= "" )
             && (!IsNumeric(l_sRenderingProviderID.value)))
        {   
            alert("Please enter valid number in Provider ID.");
            l_sRenderingProviderID.focus();
            return false;           
        }       

        if((Trim(RenderingProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sRenderingProviderID.value).length < "10") )
        {
            alert("NPI must be 10 digits.");
            l_sRenderingProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 



    }//Rendering

    if("Yes" == visibleOperatePhyInfoValue)
    {
        if(Trim(l_sOperateProviderID.value) == "")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Operating Provider ID");
            l_sOperateProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(Trim(OperateProviderIDType) == "-2" )
        {
            alert("Please Enter Operating Provider ID Type");
            selectOperateProviderIDType.focus();
            return false;
        }

        //MIPRO00050010 
        if((Trim(OperateProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sOperateProviderID.value)!= "" )
            && (!IsNumeric(l_sOperateProviderID.value)))
        {   
            alert("Please enter valid number in Provider ID.");
            l_sOperateProviderID.focus();
            return false;           
        }       

        if((Trim(OperateProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sOperateProviderID.value).length < "10") )
        {
            alert("NPI must be 10 digits.");
            l_sOperateProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 


    }//Operating

    if("Yes" == visibleOtherOperatingPhyInfoValue)
    {
        if(Trim(l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.value) == "" )
        {
            alert("Please Enter Other Operating Physician Provider ID");
            l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(Trim(OtherOperatingProviderIDType) == "-2" )
        {
            alert("Please Enter Other Operating Physician Provider ID Type");
            selectOtherOperatingProviderIDType.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 
        if((Trim(OtherOperatingProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.value)!= "" )
            && (!IsNumeric(l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.value)))
        {   
            alert("Please enter valid number in Provider ID.");
            l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.focus();
            return false;           
        }       

        if((Trim(OtherOperatingProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.value).length < "10") )
        {
            alert("NPI must be 10 digits.");
            l_sOtherOperatingProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 

    }//Other Operating

    if("Yes" == visibleReferringPhyInfoValue)
    {
        if(Trim(l_sReferringProviderID.value) == "")
        {
            alert("Please Enter Referring Physician Provider ID");
            l_sReferringProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(Trim(ReferringProviderIDType) == "-2" )
        {
            alert("Please Enter Referring Physician Provider ID Type");
            selectReferringProviderIDType.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 
        if((Trim(ReferringProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sReferringProviderID.value)!= "" )
            && (!IsNumeric(l_sReferringProviderID.value)))
        {   
            alert("Please enter valid number in Provider ID.");
            l_sReferringProviderID.focus();
            return false;           
        }       

        if((Trim(ReferringProviderIDType) == "3") && (Trim(l_sReferringProviderID.value).length < "10") )
        {
            alert("NPI must be 10 digits.");
            l_sReferringProviderID.focus();
            return false;
        }
        //MIPRO00050010 


    }//Referring
    return true;

}

</script>
```

Comment: You are using three similar but different ways to do the same thing: get a value of form element: `document....elements[...].value`, `(document....elements[...]).value` and `formElement.elements[...].value`.